# How to use bit bucket repository as a package in react project

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket-pipelines

i have a project created in React js.The project contains various features.Now i have created another project a small projects I have also pushed the code in bitbucket .now I want to use that small project as a package in my main project,how can I achieve that thing

Answer (score 0):

To pull the other repositories as a package, you should configure an ssh key pair just like pulling repo to your local via SSH. Here is my setup in Dockerfile ;

```
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG SSH_PUBLIC_KEY

# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no " > /root/.ssh/config && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config

RUN git config --global url."git@bitbucket.org:".insteadOf "https://bitbucket.org/"
```

after defining SSH variables and giving permission to them, you can run
`docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" --build-arg SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" . -t ....`

After this procedures, you can pull any repo you want.

This setup is for Docker, but you can transform it to any environment by preserving the fundamentals.